# Not able to set new value for an AngularJS custom directive isolated scope property

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a very simple custom directive and trying to pass a simple string variable from the parent scope to the custom directive isolated scope by using the '<' symbol. Then, I try to assign a new value to the variable in my custom directive controller and display the new value in the template but it's still displaying the old value.

Here is my parent controller:

```
    (function(){
      angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", ctrl);

      function ctrl(){
        ctrl = this;
        ctrl.fullname = "Paul G.";
      }
    })()
```

Here is my custom directive:

```
    (function () {
      'use strict';
      angular.module('app').directive('dir', dir);
      function dir() {
        return {
          scope:{
            name:'<',
          },
          bindToController: true,
          template: `<h1>I'm a directive</h1>
                    <h1>Name: {{vm.name}}</h1>`
          ,
          controller: function($scope){
            this.name = "Tony J";
          },
          controllerAs:'vm'
      };
     }
   })();
```

Here is my Html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html ng-app="app">

        <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <script        
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.6.4/angular-resource.js"></script> 
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="directive.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
    <p>Hello {{$ctrl.fullname}}!</p>
    <dir name="$ctrl.fullname"></dir>
    </div>
  </body> 

</html>
```

The output is below:

[image]

However, I expected it see Name: Tony J in the output.

Comment: "Tony J" is the initial value of the directive and "Paul G" is the new value provided by the parent scope using one-way binding. Read carefully about one-way and two-way binding in AngularJS before using those features.

Answer (score 1):

First a word of ***caution***

> Inputs should be using `<` and `@` bindings. The `<` symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5. The difference to `=` is that the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which means if you assign a new value to the property in the component scope, it will not update the parent scope. Note however, that both parent and component scope reference the same object, so if you are changing object properties or array elements in the component, the parent will still reflect that change. The general rule should therefore be to never change an object or array property in the component scope. `@` bindings can be used when the input is a string, especially when the value of the binding doesn't change.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

---

Now what you can do is change the value of the variable after the directive has initialized(you can study the AngularJS Component life cycle [here](http://ngninja.com/posts/angularjs-directive-life-cycle)) something like this.

```
controller: function($scope) {
    ctrl = this;
  ctrl.$onInit = function() {
    ctrl.name = "some name"
  }
},
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/gfoLnspt/) is a working fiddle I developed from your given example.

Comment: basically he does not really use the the bound variable, because $scope !== this.

Comment: @Minato thanks for the quick answer.  However, I don't understand why I need to use the $onInit. When I checked the this.name in the directive controller in the debug, it (this.name) was set correctly but the new value just didn't get reflected in the template.

Comment: @TuanLe if you have a look under console the output of [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfoLnspt/1/), You see that the `ctrl.name` is undefined initially, that inside `$onInit` it has the same value as the parent component, that is because the `scope` is bound after the controller has executed, `$onInit` makes sure that every thing is ready and then tries to modify the relevant variable.

Comment: @Minato thanks again for your answer.  I clearly understand it now.  I'm just wondering why angularJS doesn't bind the scope to the controller before the controller gets initialized.

Comment: Pre-assigning bindings was deprecated with V1.6 and will be removed in future versions. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - Breaking changes with $compile Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-compile-). The motivation was that pre-assigning does not wotk with ES6 classes and users should use the `$onInit` life-cycle hook going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of `<` (one way data binding) as an option for the `scope` property of a directive, this works with components in the property `bindings`.

If you want to do one way data binding in your isolated directive scope you can use the `@` symbol instead.